# carierwave get null on uploaded file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

iam using carierwave to post a multipart/form data. 
this is my script

```
#imagepath model 
   class Imagepath < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :imagepost
      attr_accessor :path
      mount_uploader :path, ImagepathUploader
    end

#imagepost model
class Imagepost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :imagepaths
  has_many :imagecomments
  has_many :imagelikes
  attr_accessor :imagepath_data
  # attr_accessor :path
end

    #imagepost controller post method
    # POST /imageposts
  def create
    @imagepost = Imagepost.new(imagepost_params)

    if @imagepost.save
      params[:imagepost][:imagepath_data].each do |file|
        @imagepost.imagepaths.create!(:path => file)
      end

      render json: @imagepost, status: :created, location: @imagepost
    else
      render json: @imagepost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


#imagepost_params for post_params
def imagepost_params
    params.require(:imagepost).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, :imagepath_data => [])
end
```

iam using curl to post the data

```
curl 
-F "imagepost[imagepath_data][]=c4ewt.JPG" 
-F "imagepost[imagepath_data][]=border-image.png" 
-F "imagepost[title]=asasassasa" 
-F "imagepost[description]=uhuhuhuhuhuhuh" 
-F "imagepost[user_id]=5" localhost:3000/imageposts
```

posting is work but after do post, i get path row off my imagepath table is null :(
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you've lost a `@`:

```
-F "imagepost[imagepath_data][]=@c4ewt.JPG"
```

Edit: also it'd be better to start with Rails console `bin/rails c` and inspect your DB: `Imagepath.find(17)`. It shows to you what was actually saved.

I propose to use [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and curl `-v` option for verbose output.
Here is simplified example from real project:

**report.rb**

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_images,
    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[ 'image' ].blank? }
end
```

**report_image.rb**

```
class ReportImage < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  mount_uploader :image, ReportImageUploader
end
```

**reports_controller.rb**

```
class ReportsController < YourBaseController
  # ...
  def create
    # In real project service class is used
    report = Report.create!(create_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def create_params
    params
      .require(:report)
      .permit( 
        :my_report_attribute,
        report_images_attributes: [ :kind, :image ] )

  end
end
```

and then curl:

```
curl -XPOST -v http://lvh.me:3000/yourendpoint/reports \
  -F "report[my_report_attribute]=Hehe" \
  -F "report[report_images_attributes][0][kind]=haha" \
  -F "report[report_images_attributes][0][image]=@/Users/myuser/my0.jpg" \
  -F "report[report_images_attributes][1][kind]=hoho" \
  -F "report[report_images_attributes][1][image]=@/Users/myuser/my1.png"
```

Comment: thanks its solved now. i also adding serialize :avatars, JSON  on my imagepaths model and worked now. iam suing sqlite